# onchange dropdown list from database - php, without java or ajax

Tags: php, html, sql, dynamic, onchange

I have a problem, I want to display all rows from database to dynamic onchange select form, but it displays only first or only last row. Could you please help me someone?

this is my code:

```
<?php
   $selected11 = '';
   function get_options11($vyber11) {   
      $queryyy = mysql_query("SELECT funkcia, ID_funk FROM funkcie");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryyy)) {
         $v11=$row['ID_funk'];
         $k11=$row['funkcia'];
         $moznosti11 = '';
         if($vyber11==$v11){
            $moznosti11.='<option value="'.$v11.'" selected>'.$k11.'</option>';
         } else{
            $moznosti11.='<option value="'.$v11.'">'.$k11.'</option>';}
         }
        return $moznosti11;
     }
     if(isset($_POST['funkcia'])) {
        $selected11 = $_POST['funkcia'];
     }
   }
?> 
<select name="funkcia" class="ramceky" style="width: 150px; height: 40px" onchange="this.form.submit();">
   <option><?php echo get_options11($selected11); ?></option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Sonia: first of all **mysql_* is deprecated so use mysqli_* or PDO. Second why not ajax ?

Comment: If I try mysqli_ it shows error...expects parameter 1 result..resource given. Not ajax because I want to know why it is not working.

Comment: If you are not using ajax then you have to refresh the page and I think that's not a good approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the variable `$moznosti11;` in every loop.
Move it right before while loop and it should work like charm.

See here:

```
$moznosti11 = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryyy)) {
     $v11=$row['ID_funk'];
     $k11=$row['funkcia'];

     if($vyber11==$v11){
        $moznosti11.='<option value="'.$v11.'" selected>'.$k11.'</option>';
     } else{
        $moznosti11.='<option value="'.$v11.'">'.$k11.'</option>';}
     }
    return $moznosti11;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you return with options, into one `<option>`.

Change this:

```
<option><?php echo get_options11($selected11); ?></option>
```

to this:

```
<?php echo get_options11($selected11); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a problem, it only display my problem without white frame option.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't the only problem, but it's problem. Don't put `<option>` into other `<option>` ;)